# accessing array in array data pass from controller to view of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I have this following code in my controller. I want to print the data i have my array.. should it be double forloop or foreach?

CONTROLLER:

```
public function index()
{
    $in_cart = array();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['cartProducts'])){
        $in_cart['list'] = "No Products";
    }
    else{
        foreach ($_SESSION['cartProducts'] as $key => $value) {
            $in_cart[$key] = $this->shopmod->get_one_data($key);

        }
        $cart['list'] = $in_cart;

    }


    $this->load->vars($cart);
    $data['cart'] = $this->load->view('shop/cart', '',  TRUE);
    $this->load->view('layout/default', $data);
}
```

VIEW:

```
<?php if(is_array($list)): ?>
        <?php foreach($list as  $row):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$row->name?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

but i have this following error:
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: shop/cart.php
Line Number: 18**

anyhelp guys? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is telling you exactly what is wrong.

You are trying to access the `name` property of the `$row` array when the `->` syntax is specifically reserved for objects.

To access array values, you use square brackets and keys: `<?=$row['name']?>`

Helpful hint to understand - What you're doing is quasi-equivalent to: `7->name`, insofar as the left value (7) has no idea how to use the arrow syntax. It's reserved for when the left value is an object. Not an integer, or in your case, an array.

### Update after your comment:

You would get at the data like this:

```
<? foreach($row['list'] as $r):?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$r[0]->name;?></td>
</tr>
<? endforeach;?>
```

Comment: See updated answer... after your comment - which apparently you've now removed.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Code igniter (nice!)

I would do the following to ensure the $key is taking 'name'

> public function index() {
>           foreach ($_SESSION['cartProducts'] as $key => $value) {
>               echo $key;
>           } }

Then

> public function index() {
>       $in_cart = array();
>
> ```
> if (!isset($_SESSION['cartProducts'])){
>     $in_cart['list'] = "No Products";
> }
> else{
>     foreach ($_SESSION['cartProducts'] as $key => $value) {
>         $in_cart[$key] = $this->shopmod->get_one_data($key);
>
>     }
> }
>
>
> $this->load->vars($cart);
> $data['cart'] = $this->load->view('shop/cart', '',  TRUE);
> $data['list'] = $in_cart;
> $this->load->view('layout/default', $data); }
> ```